# Take the iterative elements of a list and append it to another list

Tags: python

I want to make a list and the elemets of this list comes from user input from Flask. Here is my code to do this:

```
    data = pd.read_csv('data_file_path.csv')
    data = list(data.columns)
```

The output for this line is:

```
['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']
```

I am using Flask to get the user input (one element at a time as a dropdown input) which is:

```
columns = [request.form.get('columns')]
```

Finally, I created an empty list and appended the user element into that list, here is the code:

```
    list1 = []

    try:
        for line in columns:
            list1.append(line)
        print(list1)

    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Complete code is:

```
    data = pd.read_csv('File_Path.csv')
    data = list(data.columns)
    columns = [request.form.get('columns')]

    list1 = []

    try:
        for line in columns:
            list1.append(line)
        print(list1)

    except TypeError:
        pass
```

But, I am getting output like bellow and everytime when I give an new input previous one get deleted. (when I selected A1 from dropdown)

```
Finaloutput: ['A1']
```

I want to make a list like this (append when user select column from dropdown and it add to the final list) which means if a user select an element from dropdown then it's add to the list but previous one won't deleted. Like this (if i select A1 to A5 from user input)

```
['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']
```

Comment: So you have a list `['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5']` and want to create a new identical list?

Comment: What is the length of `columns`?

Comment: Yes, I have a list like that, passing the list element from dropdown at a time and make a new list which I have selected from dropdown only. Problem is, first input I am getting it correctly but when I select second input first one deleted and second one enter to the list. Although I want both

Comment: Length of the column is 26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare your array outside your api endpoint. Otherwise the array will be emptied in every api call:

```
list1 = []
@app.get("/")
def add_item(request):
    columns = [request.form.get('columns')]
    try:
        for line in columns:
            list1.append(line)
        print(list1)

    except TypeError:
        pass
```

Notice in the above code i am declaring `list1` as a global variable, so the items i append to it will persist on time.

**NOTE**: The data in `list1` will only persist in memory, when you stop your service, the data will be lost. If you want to persist your data even when you stop the service, you need to save it in a database.

Comment: Sounds like you are sending data to server in a wrong way. Apparently you are sending a plain array like `"friends"` so, when you iterate in `for line in columns`, you are iterating in single characters. Your code is prepared to receive data in an array, so you should send data in that way, like `["friends"]`.